# Extremely poor performance for ZFS 4k randwrite on NVMe compared to XFS?

Tags: zfs, xfs, nvme, fio

I've been a fan of ZFS for a long time and I use it on my home NAS, but in testing its viability for production workloads I've found that its performance is inconceivably bad compared with XFS on the same disks.  Testing on an Intel P4510 8TB disk using fio 3.21 using these settings:

```
fio \
--name=xfs-fio \
--size=10G \
-group_reporting \
--time_based \
--runtime=300 \
--bs=4k \
--numjobs=64 \
--rw=randwrite \
--ioengine=sync \
--directory=/mnt/fio/
```

Results look like this:

```
xfs-fio: (groupid=0, jobs=64): err= 0: pid=63: Mon Feb  1 21:46:44 2021
  write: IOPS=189k, BW=738MiB/s (774MB/s)(216GiB/300056msec); 0 zone resets
    clat (usec): min=2, max=2430.4k, avg=336.28, stdev=4745.39
     lat (usec): min=2, max=2430.4k, avg=336.38, stdev=4745.40
    clat percentiles (usec):
     |  1.00th=[     7],  5.00th=[    10], 10.00th=[    10], 20.00th=[    11],
     | 30.00th=[    12], 40.00th=[    14], 50.00th=[    23], 60.00th=[    35],
     | 70.00th=[    36], 80.00th=[    37], 90.00th=[    39], 95.00th=[    40],
     | 99.00th=[    44], 99.50th=[  8455], 99.90th=[ 66323], 99.95th=[ 70779],
     | 99.99th=[179307]
   bw (  KiB/s): min=95565, max=7139939, per=100.00%, avg=757400.32, stdev=21559.21, samples=38262
   iops        : min=23890, max=1784976, avg=189327.65, stdev=5389.87, samples=38262
  lat (usec)   : 4=0.03%, 10=13.41%, 20=36.22%, 50=49.56%, 100=0.12%
  lat (usec)   : 250=0.13%, 500=0.01%, 750=0.01%, 1000=0.01%
  lat (msec)   : 2=0.01%, 4=0.01%, 10=0.01%, 20=0.01%, 50=0.01%
  lat (msec)   : 100=0.46%, 250=0.02%, 500=0.01%, 750=0.01%, 1000=0.01%
  lat (msec)   : 2000=0.01%, >=2000=0.01%
  cpu          : usr=0.27%, sys=7.34%, ctx=793590, majf=0, minf=116620
  IO depths    : 1=100.0%, 2=0.0%, 4=0.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     issued rwts: total=0,56715776,0,0 short=0,0,0,0 dropped=0,0,0,0
     latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=1Run status group 0 (all jobs):
  WRITE: bw=738MiB/s (774MB/s), 738MiB/s-738MiB/s (774MB/s-774MB/s), io=216GiB (232GB), run=300056-300056msecDisk stats (read/write):
  nvme7n1: ios=25/21951553, merge=0/173138, ticks=4/660308, in_queue=265520, util=21.39%real
```

On ZFS, with this zpool create:

```
# zpool create -o ashift=13 -o autoreplace=on nvme6 /dev/nvme6n1
```

And this volume create:

```
zfs create              \
    -o mountpoint=/mnt/nvme6 \
    -o atime=off             \
    -o compression=lz4       \
    -o dnodesize=auto        \
    -o primarycache=metadata \
    -o recordsize=128k       \
    -o xattr=sa              \
    -o acltype=posixacl      \
    nvme6/test0
```

The results look like this:

```
zfs-fio: (groupid=0, jobs=64): err= 0: pid=64: Mon Feb  1 23:00:41 2021
  write: IOPS=28.3k, BW=110MiB/s (116MB/s)(32.3GiB/300004msec); 0 zone resets
    clat (usec): min=7, max=314789, avg=2258.78, stdev=2509.17
     lat (usec): min=7, max=314790, avg=2259.28, stdev=2509.22
    clat percentiles (usec):
     |  1.00th=[   52],  5.00th=[   70], 10.00th=[   81], 20.00th=[  106],
     | 30.00th=[  225], 40.00th=[ 1057], 50.00th=[ 1713], 60.00th=[ 2606],
     | 70.00th=[ 3458], 80.00th=[ 4146], 90.00th=[ 4948], 95.00th=[ 5669],
     | 99.00th=[ 8455], 99.50th=[12256], 99.90th=[25560], 99.95th=[30540],
     | 99.99th=[39060]
   bw (  KiB/s): min=51047, max=455592, per=100.00%, avg=113196.01, stdev=702.99, samples=38272
   iops        : min=12761, max=113897, avg=28297.59, stdev=175.73, samples=38272
  lat (usec)   : 10=0.01%, 20=0.01%, 50=0.80%, 100=16.73%, 250=12.93%
  lat (usec)   : 500=2.45%, 750=2.97%, 1000=3.37%
  lat (msec)   : 2=14.91%, 4=23.92%, 10=21.20%, 20=0.50%, 50=0.19%
  lat (msec)   : 100=0.01%, 250=0.01%, 500=0.01%
  cpu          : usr=0.31%, sys=7.39%, ctx=11163058, majf=0, minf=32449
  IO depths    : 1=100.0%, 2=0.0%, 4=0.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     issued rwts: total=0,8476060,0,0 short=0,0,0,0 dropped=0,0,0,0
     latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=1Run status group 0 (all jobs):
  WRITE: bw=110MiB/s (116MB/s), 110MiB/s-110MiB/s (116MB/s-116MB/s), io=32.3GiB (34.7GB), run=300004-300004msecreal
```

XFS did 189k iops, ZFS did 28.3k iops - an 85% decrease - with equivalent decrease in throughput.  CPUs are dual Xeon 6132, this machine's kernel is 4.15.0-62-generic, though I've seen the same effects on 5.x kernels as well.

Comment: I slightly prefer XFS to ZFS for these type of workloads but even I have to say this is a classically bad workload for an untuned ZFS. You MUST [understand the role of ZFS' recordsize when trying perform this type of benchmarking](https://serverfault.com/a/1021299/203726) - it really is that essential. Maybe you can post an answer to your question as to why?

Comment: This isn't surprising to me, because ZFS is ***not*** fast.  It has never been fast. ZFS performance can often best be described as "pig-like".  All you can do is throw a lot of hardware at it and then try to tune it to make it "not-as-slow-as-it-is-by-default".  ZFS is a lot of great things but "fast" has never been one of them.

Comment: Adjusting the recordsize to 4k I was able to get the ZFS iops up to 38k, which is better than it was with default settings, but still ~80% slower than xfs.  Anyway, I think that thread and the comments here are enough that it seems like my results aren't an anomaly.  Thanks all.

Comment: (You're welcome - feel free to post an answer to your own question and you can even accept it!)